# C# Interactive - Project References and Settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio

With the Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 there now is a C# Interactive tool window built into Visual Studio.

The new tool window is invoked by going to View → Other Windows → C# Interactive.

Is there any way to have the C# Interactive tool load the set of references, app settings, IOC config etc. for a project in the solution?

Answer (score 1):

This only works for .NET Framework projects:

You can context-click a project in your solution explorer and choose "Initialize interactive with project". Then the interactive window will load all references and your project's dll.

It will only load the dlls, no config. You could still do that manually though, aswell as the IOC config, by calling the startup.cs yourself.

This doesn't work for .NET Core or .NET standard projects.